# Select length as minute:seconds format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to convert seconds to a minute:seconds format.
e.g. 207 seconds would be 3:27
I have a table with column length that has the length of songs stored in seconds.

Using this query almost works, however, when a song should be 3:03 it will instead show 3:3

```
select concat(Length/60, ':', Length%60) as Length from songs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Convert(nvarchar, (Length/60)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + Convert(nvarchar, Length%60), 2) as Length from songs
```

Answer (score 1):

I build this using a varaible since I didn't have your table, but try this:

```
declare @length int = 207

select concat(@Length/60, ':', case len(@Length%60) when 1 then '0' else '' end, @Length%60) as [leng]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateadd to do that:

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(second, 187, 0), 108)
```

This returns "00:03:07" so you can cut away hours if you don't need them.